# Getting data from the function using an Object in CF

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, cfml

I have a CFC object and a function which gets me the data which I want. Now I want to use that data and provide it to an already defined **custom tag** attribute. When I dump the `#iEngine.listScore()#` I get some parameters. But my problem is how should I provide those to an attribute?

```
<cfdump var="#iEngine.listScores()#" label="Swapnil Test - Function ListScore">     
<cfset filename="ACE_DataExtract_#DateFormat(now(),'dd.mmm.yyyy')#.xls" />
<!--- Calling Custom tags to create/output xls files --->
<cfmodule template="#request.library.customtags.virtualpath#excel.cfm" file="#filename#" sheetname="ACE Report">

  <cfmodule template="#request.library.customtags.virtualpath#exceldata.cfm"
    query="#iEngine.listScores()#" 
    action="AddWorksheet" 
    sheetname="ACE Report" 
    colorscheme="blue" 
    useheaders="true" 
    contentformat="#{bold=true}#"
    customheaders="#ListScore#">
      <cfoutput>Excel Extract - ACE Report - #DateFormat(Now(),"d-mmm-yyyy")#</cfoutput>
  </cfmodule>   
</cfmodule>
```

Here I want to provide the data of `iEngine.listScore()` to the "Query" attribute in "exceldata" custom tag.

Below is the dump of `iEngine.listScore()`

[image: Dump of iengine.listscore]

Comment: query=iEngine.listScores() should work. No double quotes, no pound signs. Moreover, it looks like your custom tag expects Query, while the dump you show is a structure

Comment: Correct. My custom tag expects query. I will try to put directly as you suggested; will let you know. thanks

Comment: you will need to modify your function too, so that returntype is query. good luck & happy coding :)

Comment: To clarify, query=iEngine.listScores() would only work IF `iEngine.listScores()` returned a query - which it does not. It returns an array of structures. So you either need to modify the CFC method so it returns a query and pass that object into the custom tag OR modify the custom tag to accept an array of structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a transform Data function to change your array-struct to a query object, then pass that on....

```
<cffunction name="transformData" result="query">
    <cfargument name="inArray" type="array">

    <cfset local.qryReturn = queryNew("actiondate,actionId,closedate")>
    <!--- You may look up queryNew and also set your dataTypes --->

    <cfloop array="#arguments.inArray#" index="i">
        <cfset QueryAddRow(local.qryReturn)>
        <cfset querySetCell(local.qryReturn,"actionDate",i["actiondate"])>
        <cfset querySetCell(local.qryReturn,"actionid",i["actionid"])>
        <cfset querySetCell(local.qryReturn,"closedate",i["closedate"])>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn local.qryReturn>
</cffunction>

<cfset test = [
    {actiondate='1/1/2015',actionid=134,closedate=''},
    {actiondate='1/2/2015',actionid=135,closedate=''},
    {actiondate='1/3/2015',actionid=136,closedate=''}
]>

<cfdump var="#test#">

<cfset resultQry = transformData(test)>
<cfif NOT isquery(resultQry)>
    Exit invalid Data.
<cfelse>
    <cfdump var="#resultQry#">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Before you roll-your-own, do not forget about cflib.org. Chances are ["they have a function for that..."](http://www.cflib.org/udf/ArrayOfStructuresToQuery) ;-)